# Forcing a NumericUpDown control to only accept powers of two

Tags: c#, winforms

I present the user a NumericUpDown control so he can specify the size of a texture. It is important that this texture is of power of two size (32, 64, 128...).

I have tried to force the control to present only this powers of two whenever you click the up or down buttons (or push the arrow keys) in the event ValueChanged without luck. I also have tried using the Increment property. All the solutions I have encountered by myself are either too hacky or have special case in which it shows invalid values.

Is there an easy way (or at least not too tricky) to achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inherit the `UpDownBase` class.

Comment: I'll look at UpDownBase. It may be cool to make a custom control I can reuse throughout the project.

Comment: I have made a custom PowerOfTwoUpDown to great effect. It is very easy. You need only to override UpButton(), DownButton() and UpdateEditText(). To make it like the standard NumericUpDown, I've made also a custom Value, Minimum and Maximum. It looks good and does what I wanted! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to run into a problem in 2+ digit numbers. If I want to put `32` and you see the `3` as I am typing, then your program would just tell me I'm wrong. Validate it when you submit your data.

Comment: That is not a problem, because the textbox part is read-only. The user can only interact with the up/down arrows.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a `ComboBox`, you will have your numbers dropped down, you support auto complete and  at the same time escape the validation of user input, code like:

```
//generate your array.
List<string> twos = new List<string>();

int item = 2;
int max = int.MaxValue / 2;
while ((item = 2 * item) < max)
{
    twos.Add(item.ToString());
}

ComboBox comboBox1 = new ComboBox();

comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;

//comboBox1.Items.Clear();
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(twos.ToArray());
comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(twos.ToArray());

this.Controls.Add(comboBox1);
```

Comment: That is the option I have as plan B, but I'd prefer the NumericUpDown alternative. It may be silly, but I think it seems a more elegant option for the user. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, well you could make your own.
Using a textbox and a couple picture boxes you can set up a form that sets only powers of two.

Comment: No, don't do that. Do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721742/forcing-a-numericupdown-control-to-only-accept-powers-of-two/6721761#6721761).